# How to format a number to appear as percentage in Excel

Tags: excel, text, format, percentage

So lets say I have a few numbers in a sheet

```
    a   b   c   d
1   33  53  23  11
2   42  4   83  64
3   75  3   48  38
4   44  0   22  45
5   2   34  76  6
6               
7   Total   85
```

I would like to display those numbers so that the cell value still holds the original figure (A1 = 33)
but the cell displays both the number and a percentage from the total (B7) eg

```
    a           b            c           d
1   33 (39%)    53 (62%)     23 (27%)    11 (13%)
2   42 (49%)    4 (5%)       83 (98%)    64 (75%)
3   75 (88%)    3 (4%)       48 (56%)    38 (45%)
4   44 (52%)    0 (0%)       22 (26%)    45 (53%)
5   2 (2%)      34 (40%)     76 (89%)    6 (7%)
6               
7   Total       85
```

I know how to format a cell as a percentage, but I can't figure out how to display both original values, the calculated percentage value (value/total*100), but not change the cell value so I could still sum the cells in the end (eg. A6 =SUM(A1:A5) = 196)

Does anyone have an idea? I was hoping there could be a way to duplicate and calculate the figure using text formatting, but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible either, because formatting pulls all information from the cell you apply it itself, and I don't know any way of referencing something from another cell into the formatting of another.

Comment: is the data in A1:D5 calculated, or just raw numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a trivial answer and maybe not what you're looking for, but why not just add a column for each of the columns you have now?

```
    a  a'       b  b'       c  c'       d  d'
1   33 (39%)   53 (62%)     23 (27%)    11 (13%)
2   42 (49%)    4 (5%)      83 (98%)    64 (75%)
3   75 (88%)    3 (4%)      48 (56%)    38 (45%)
4   44 (52%)    0 (0%)      22 (26%)    45 (53%)
5   2  (2%)    34 (40%)     76 (89%)    6  (7%)
6               
7   Total      85
```

Comment: I thought of that, but I would rather find a formatting solution. I don't want to have repeating information, and I have a lot more columns than this example.

Comment: I guessed so :)
In any case, I think the problem is that you are trying to hold two different pieces of information in the same cell (the raw value and the percentage it represents from the total) and that can't really be done AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

@Ari’s answer seems to meet to meet the requirements in your question, not repeat information more than the example you gave for output requirement and be viable for up to around 8000 or so columns to start with (unless a very old version of Excel) and Jerry’s comment is also correct that what you want to achieve the way you want to achieve it is not possible.

However there are other approaches that might be acceptable substitutes. One is to copy your data and Paste Special with Operation Divide, either elsewhere or over the top of your data. If over the top this either shows the values or the percentages otherwise duplicates your data. Over the top would also require something like Operation Multiply to revert back to values, and reformatting each time if to appear as in your example.

Another is to use a PivotTable with some calculated fields and both are shown below:

[image: SO18397910 example]

I appreciate neither is exactly what you are asking for.